# Has there been a study comparing stress level or burnout between different occupations that provide therapy?

Tags: reference-request, io-psychology, stress

For instance consider psychiatrist, clinical psychologist, clinical social worker, family/marriage therapists, occupational therapists (in some places they can provide therapy), professional counselors, etc.

I've found research articles talking about stressful careers in general but not comparison. Wiki contributors cite an article from the 80s saying, "Professions with high levels of burnout include social workers, nurses, teachers, lawyers, engineers, medical practitioners, customer service representatives, and police officers.  One reason why burnout is so prevalent within the human services field is due in part to the high-stress work environment and emotional demands of the job."

Comment: I, like you, have been unable to find any direct comparisons among different specific occupations inside therapy. But plenty comparing general groups like public safety, teachers, nurses, and social workers. I'm going to look a bit more. I imagine the majority of these studies try to aggregate fields for ease of work.

Comment: Yes, you're right, likely that they aggregate them unless the comparison is only for careers within the same field.  I'm not sure what the major obstacle is to research in this area, disappointing that I have had no luck finding anything.